# How visual basic random generator works?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, random

How does visual basic create the random number? I know how to make a random number generator, and I know what it does (randomly generates a number) but I would like to know how. The problem that occurs when trying to research this question is everything explains how to make one, not how the computer does it. In my programming class people are always talking about how visual basic has a better random generator than lots of other languages, but they have never backed up this claim, and I am curious to know how the vb generator works.

Comment: VB.NET is a language, it doesn't know beans about random numbers.  The System.Random or the System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator classes are part of the .NET Framework and usable in any language.  They are not "better" when you call them from a VB.NET program of course.

Comment: The Visual Basic RNG may not be the best one around, perhaps you are referring to the .NET one. As well as Martin's answer, you should look at the remarks section of [.NET Random Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a true random number generator.  All computers are driven by algorithms, so are deterministic in the end, so are never truly random and can be predicted (even if difficult).  Some are called pseudo-random number generators, and are effectively random for purposes of security.  You can see how the .NET Random class is implemented here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs#bb77e610694e64catrue

That implementation isn't secure enough for security-related uses though, which you would use the RandomNumberGenerator class for, which is based on the Windows Cryptographic APIs (which are closed source).  The wrapper around that has the source here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/randomnumbergenerator.cs#828597225647bdbb